# General geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry

How to solve the following:

Let $f : (M,\nabla)\rightarrow (\overline{M},\overline{\nabla})$ be a diffeomorphism of manifolds with torsion-free connections.

a) For reparametrisation $\alpha$ of geodesic line on M holds $\nabla_{T_\alpha}T_{\alpha}=
\rho(t)T_\alpha$, and conversely, if tangent field of curve satisfies this condition, then exits its reparametrisation that is geodesic. Prove. (These curves we can call general geodesics.)

b) Diffeomorfism $f$ is a geodesic map if image of general geodesic on manifold M is general geodesic on $\overline{M}$. By identifying $f$ connected vector-fields
$M$ and $\overline{M}$: $P(X,Y)=\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y-\nabla_{X}Y$. Prove that $P$ is symmetric and $F$-bilinear map. Conclude that $P(X,Y)= \psi(Y)X+\psi(X)Y$, where $\psi$ is a form. By using vector-fields of coordinate frame, find $\psi$.

For a torsionless connection we have: $\nabla_{X}Y-\nabla_{Y}X=[X,Y]$. $P$ is a $F$-bilinear map, since it is $F$-linear by first coordinate:
\begin{align*}P(X,f_1 Y_1+f_2 Y_2)&=\nabla_{X}(f_1 Y_1+f_2 Y_2)-\overline\nabla_{X}(f_1 Y_1+f_2 Y_2)\\
&=\nabla_{X}f_1 Y_1+\nabla_{X} f_2 Y_2-\overline\nabla_{X}f_1 Y_1-\overline\nabla_{X}f_2 Y_2\\
&=X(f_1)Y_1+f_1\nabla_{X}Y_1+X(f_2)Y_2+f_2\nabla_{X}Y_2\\
  &\quad -X(f_1)Y_1-f_1\overline\nabla_{X} Y_1-X(f_2)Y_2-f_2\overline\nabla_{X} Y_2\\
&=f_1(\nabla_{X}Y_1-\overline\nabla_{X}Y_1)+f_2 (\nabla_{X}Y_2-\overline\nabla_{X}Y_2)\\
&=f_1 P(X,Y_1)+f_2 P(X,Y_2),\end{align*}
and similarly, it is $F$-linear by second coordinate.

How to deduce what is $\psi$? Also, how to prove a statement for general geodesics?

Detailed explanations are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: while you probably do welcome detailed explanations, we also welcome explanations of what you have tried to do... This looks like an exercise from a book (and hopefully not an exam!) Where did it come from?

Comment: It was theorem formulated in lectures I attend, but without proof, so I would like to know how to prove that or where can I read more on that topic that will help me understanding... Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what have you tried to do? If you did try something, we might be able to help you carry out the idea. If you have not tried anything, then the best plan would be to try something, spend a few days on the problem and then come back. If you are facing a problem at this level, you probaably have some ideas on how to proceed!